# NestJS treats 2 different actions as the same in Guard

Tags: routes, nestjs

Guard

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {
    super();
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>("isPublicKey", [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);

    if (isPublic) return true;

    return super.canActivate(context);
  }
}
```

2 get controllers with different paths.

```
  @Get(':id')
  findOneById(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.storesService.findOne(id);
  }

  @Get('/current')
  @SetMetadata("isPublicKey", true)
  currentStore(@Req() request: any) {
    console.log(request);
  }
```

When I send get request `http://127.0.0.1:8000/stores/current` reflector doesn't find the flag "isPublicKey". But In context, I see an object route with another path.

[image]

But if I delete the `findOneById` method, then all works correctly, and in the route object in context, I see the correct route same as the original route.

[image]

Comment: read the hint block on this: https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#route-parameters

Answer (score 3):

Change the order of the methods.

If you call `/current`, the first method that fits will be called.
In this case `/:id` (with the id 'current')